# Как сделать, чтобы в ячейку можно было вставить только значения?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Нужно написать макрос, который будет блокировать вставку формата (шрифта, цвет и пр.), чтобы в ячейку вносился только текст.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.clearFormat();
}
```

Заметим, что [триггер **onEdit**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) сработает лишь при ручном вводе данных, включая копирование из буфера обмена. Тем не менее, после ввода данных пользователь сможет изменить формат ячейки беспрепятственно. Таким образом, полностью предотвратить форматирование таким образом не удастся.